# rollup generated vue component not invoked as custom vue tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, rollup

I was following this example:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html

I'd like to render a vue custom tag named "flex-text" with this html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>runtime</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
    <script src="/lib/mk-vue-flex-text.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <flex-text
    name="test"
    value="text"></flex-text>
  </body>
</html>
```

The javascript code for "/lib/mk-vue-flex-text.js" is being loaded (seriously, I've checked).

My wrapper code (based on ) looks like this:

```
import component from '../src/mk-vue-flex-text.vue';

export function install(Vue) {
  if (install.installed) return;
  install.installed = true;
  Vue.component('flex-text', component);
}

const plugin = { install };

// Auto-install when vue is found (eg. in browser via <script> tag)
let GlobalVue = null;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  GlobalVue = window.Vue;
} else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
  GlobalVue = global.Vue;
}
if (GlobalVue) {
  GlobalVue.use(plugin);
}
// To allow use as module (npm/webpack/etc.) export component
export default component;
```

The vue-Component seems to be properly transpiled into 'mk-vue-flex-text.js':

```
var FlexText = (function (exports) {
  'use strict';
  // lots of stuff etc.

  // ...
  // generated app code 
  // ...

  // Import vue component

  // Declare install function executed by Vue.use()
  function install(Vue) {
    if (install.installed) { return; }
    install.installed = true;
    Vue.component('flex-text', __vue_component__);
  }

  //  Create module definition for Vue.use()
  var plugin = {
    install: install,
  };

  // Auto-install when vue is found (eg. in browser via <script> tag)
  var GlobalVue = null;
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = window.Vue;
  } else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = global.Vue;
  }
  if (GlobalVue) {
    GlobalVue.use(plugin);
  }

  exports.default = __vue_component__;
  exports.install = install;

  return exports;

}({}));
```

So, it all looks ok to me. But still the component is not being rendered.

Comment: Did you intialize Vue yet? I can't see that you're having any "root" element, which Vue should be initialized on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: I might be wrong, but according to https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html#Base-Example defining a root element should not be necessary.

Comment: You're right, it should work like that, can you replicate this in a codepen?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/mikekastner/pen/wvBgJEq